# Perl regex syntax for single letter hex

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, scripting

In perl I am trying to use a regex to search through specific hex characters but i'm not sure if the xB syntax is valid (ie to refer to the Vertical Tab character) or whether it should just be \B?  Also, is x9 valid or should it just be 9?

```
perl -ane '{ if(m/([\x0-\x9]|[\xB-\xC]|[\xE-\x1F]|[\x7F-\xFF])/) { print } }'
```

Comment: What does "hex characters" mean? `[0-9A-Fa-f]`? Or specific values in some defined charset?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?
Tab is `\x09`

Comment: *Vertical* tab is `\x0B`

Comment: Everything is hexadecimal. 'Z' is 0x7A in my system. Are you trying to match 'Z'? Or do you want to match characters that *represent* hexadecimal values? What for you want to use? Pairs? 00 01 02... C style? (0xAA, 0xFF) Mainframe style? (x'00, x'FF)?

Comment: if I put in x1F then I want to match the Unit Separator character

Comment: Still don't know what is your problem. The regular expression `/x[0-9A-Z]{2}/` will match the string "this is a x1A test." The reason I ask what do you want to achieve is that your question is ambiguous, so there are many "right" answers to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -lne 'print if /[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\xff]/'
```

Documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes:

> [Some sequences, including] \x are also special and have the same meanings as they do outside a bracketed character class.

Comment: And to more directly answer part of the question (it's implicit in your answer): `\x9` shouldn't be used; instead spell it `\x09` or `\x{9}`.